# SQL: Exclude row if value in both columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where I want to SELECT everything in two columns but exclude all the rows where the value are equal to each other. Is this possible?

Lets say it looks like this:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| Login            | Alias            |
+------------------+------------------+
| user1@domain.com | user1@domain.com |
| user1@domain.com | user1@example.com|
| user1@domain.com | user7@domain.com |
| user2@domain.com | user2@domain.com |
| user3@domain.com | user3@domain.com |
+------------------+------------------+
```

And all I want is this:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| Login            | Alias            |
+------------------+------------------+
| user1@domain.com | user1@example.com|
| user1@domain.com | user7@domain.com |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Is this possible with a SQL Query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Login <> Alias
```

Comment: That was quick and easy! Thank you very much. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, Alias, 
   case 
      when Login=Alias  then 'true' 
      else 'false' 
   end 
from TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual for the Comparison Operators: **http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx**

Whilst `!=` will work, it is not an ISO standard operator. This means that it will be less portable.

I recommend you use the ISO standard operator `<>`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx

```
SELECT login
     , alias
FROM   your_table
WHERE  login <> alias
```

You might be thinking "why does using a standard matter to me?!". Well, the first time you ever have to go through a migration from one DBMS to another you will be most grateful for doing things the *"more correct"* way.